# How do I go to the API's second page when all 1000 arrays had been searched

Tags: javascript, api, discord.js

I have this code, It searches a site for a specific `item_name`. But it only searches the first page of the site. So I made some changes, I added `k` and `kRequired`. But the problem is that I got an error code that says that `getItemFind` is not defined. I cannot spam requests to the API either because if I reach a certain amount of requests per second, my API key is going to get disabled.

```js
if (command === 'item') {
    var k = 0
    var kRequired = 0
    var itemFinder = message.content.substring(6)
    for (var j = 0; j <= 1000; j++) {
        console.log("searching")
        if (j >= 950) {
            console.log('next page!')
            kRequired = ++k
            j = 0
        }
        if (k === kRequired) {
            console.log("searching next page!")
            let getItemFind = async () => {
                let response = await axios.get(`https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=<API-KEY>&page=${k}`);
                let itemFind = response.data;
                k = ++k
                j = 0
                return itemFind;
            }
        }
        let itemFindValue = await getItemFind();
        var searchItem = itemFindValue.auctions[j].item_name
        var itemFound = searchItem.toUpperCase().includes(itemFinder.toUpperCase())
        if (itemFound === true) {
            var itemNameDescription = itemFindValue.auctions[j].item_name
            var itemDescription = itemFindValue.auctions[j].item_lore
            var itemDescription = itemDescription.split(/§./).join("");
            const itemEmbed = {
                color: 0x0099ff,
                title: `${itemNameDescription}`,
                fields: [{
                    title: `\u200b`,
                    value: `${itemDescription}`,
                    inline: false,
                }],
                timestamp: new Date(),
                footer: {
                    text: '?help [command | category]',
                },
            };
            message.channel.send({
                embed: itemEmbed
            })
            return j
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keywords `let` and `const` behave differently from `var`. If you define a variable with `let` or `const` inside of a code block `{...}` then the variables you created are only available inside that block.

```
// begin code block
if (k === kRequired) {
    console.log("searching next page!")
    // this is only available in this block of code
    let getItemFind = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get(`https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=<API-KEY>&page=${k}`);
        let itemFind = response.data;
        k = ++k
        j = 0
        return itemFind;
    }
}
// end code block
let itemFindValue = await getItemFind();
```

In your case, you have defined the function `getItemFind` inside of an `if` block. There are many ways to fix this. One of the simplest is to just move the variable declaration to the top of the function scope.

Here is an example to show you what I mean

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
if (a < b) {
    let c = 3;
    console.log('c inside code block', c)
}
console.log('c outside of code block', c)
```

Comment: I don't understand / I don't see any difference you put in your code to mine's

Comment: There is no difference in the code. I was just explaining what you need to do. Look at the comments in the code

Comment: i'll post an example